# How to insert a column inbetween other columns (Perl Spreadsheet::WriteExcel)

Tags: perl, excel, spreadsheet

Lets say I have the following spreadsheet that I can parse in perl which looks like this:

[image]

I want to insert a column between Column1 and Column2. So end result looks like this:

[image]

It doesn't look like there is a set method for this in Spreadsheet-WriteExcel.

Does anyone know an easy way of doing this in Perl?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only(*) thing that `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` can do is write spreadsheets. It doesn't have any facilities for reading an existing spreadsheet. Using it to modify an existing spreadsheet would involve first reading it with some other method (like `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`) and then writing a brand new spreadsheet with the data the way you want it. Note that if you try this, you will lose macros, graphs, and any other feature that `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` doesn't support.

The documentation for `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` goes over a lot of the alternatives. See the [`WRITING EXCEL FILES`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel#WRITING_EXCEL_FILES) and [`MODIFYING AND REWRITING EXCEL FILES`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel#MODIFYING_AND_REWRITING_EXCEL_FILES) sections. `Win32::OLE` for instance, gives you full access to Excel's internals with all the power and ease-of-use you'd expect from a Microsoft API. I'll leave it to you to judge whether any of these approaches qualify as "easy".

(*) - I don't mean that in a bad way. A Perl module that can write spreadsheets is pretty freaking cool.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response mob! I guess I should have mentioned that I am using ParseExcel to read the spreadsheet... Anyway, I see what you are saying :). So in essence it is not possible to do the column insertion in an "easy" way with the Spreadsheet modules that exist for Perl. Many thanks for you response!

Comment: Has the situation with perl changed at all in the past  4 years or so?